# Gensim word2vec: iterator does not stop with yield

Tags: python, gensim, word2vec

I have this sentences iterator that is using `yield` so it's formally a generator

```
from gensim.utils import simple_preprocess
from gensim.parsing.preprocessing import STOPWORDS
import json
import os

class LyricsCorpus(object):

    def __init__(self, corpus, tokenize=False, deaccent=False):
        self.corpus = corpus
        self.tokenize = tokenize
        self.deaccent = deaccent

    def __iter__(self):
        for index,fname in enumerate( os.listdir(self.corpus) ):
            with open( os.path.join(self.corpus, fname) ) as data_file:
                data = json.load(data_file)
                for item in data:
                    if "lyrics" in item:
                        if "lyrics_body" in item["lyrics"]:
                            if self.tokenize:
                                yield self.tokens( item["lyrics"]["lyrics_body"] )
                            else:
                                yield item["lyrics"]["lyrics_body"].split()
    '''
        This lowercases, tokenizes, de-accents (optional). – the output are final tokens = unicode strings, that won’t be processed any further.
    '''
    def tokens(self,text):
        return [token for token in simple_preprocess(text, deacc=self.deaccent, min_len=2, max_len=15) if token not in STOPWORDS]
```

when running into `Word2vec` like

```
min_count = 1
size = 50
window = 4
model = Word2Vec(corpus_iterator, min_count=min_count, size=size, window=window)
```

the iterator does not stop, *looping through the files in the corpus folder indefinitively*. This does not happen in a ordinary iteration like

```
from LyricsCorpus import *
it=LyricsCorpus('./corpus')
[item for k in it]
```

Comment: What do you mean by *it does not stop*?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham just clarified, it basically loops through the files indefinitely. This does not happen if I just load one file and yields items in it.

Comment: So it loops over the same files more than once? Also I presume you mean `[item for item in it]`?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham so if I do `[item for item in it]` it consumes the items and stops at the end. If i go through `Word2Vec` it hangs looping from files 0,1,...,N,0,1,...N, etc. I assume the runtime should raise a `StopIteration` at the last `next` or maybe it's `Word2vec` that ignore this.

Comment: Is the default not to iterate 6 times? If you add `iter=1` what happens?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham why `6`? the external iteration must be `len( os.listdir(self.corpus) )` i.e. the number of files in the folder. In the inner loop the function loads the json from each file and do like `yield item` that is a item in the json array, so it is `len(data)`.

Comment: The default according to the docs is 5, you do iter+1 iterations

Comment: @PadraicCunningham please point me to the docs, thank you!

Comment: https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/develop/gensim/models/word2vec.py#L360. That is what you are using yes?

Comment: If you search iter=5 here https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html you will see it too, the first pass builds the structure and the subsequent train the model from what I understand.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham you were right, it did the `iter=5` iterations! Lost in the parameters it seems. Thank you sir.

Comment: No prob, you're welcome.